# Finding a Row with a Partial Match in another Data Frame and then writing its output into the original DF

Tags: r, string, dataframe, for-loop

I have a data frame "zadavatele" and data frame "Final_Town_Contacts".  In the df zadavatele, there is a column "buyer_name" with the name and in df "Final_Town_Contacts" there is a column "Name" and "id". The problem is that the formats of the names are a bit different so I can't use the match function. The column "buyer_name" contains the name along with other words, hence it contains the full contents of the column "Name" and some other characters. The other problem is that not all towns included in the "zadavatele" df are included in "Final_Town_Contacts".

I want to find matching towns and then write the variable "id" from the data frame "Final_Town_Contacts" for the corresponding town in "zadavatele".

To demonstrate what I would like to do, here are the two data frames:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  buyer_name
  <chr>     
1 xx abc    
2 y fdg     
3 z sad
```

```
 Name     id
  <chr> <dbl>
1 y        54
2 z        11
3 x        32
```

I would like to have this output in the "zadavatele" data frame:

```
 buyer_name     id
  <chr> <dbl>
1 xx abc        32
2 y fdg        54
3 z sad        11
```

I was thinking of using a for loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(zadavatele)) {
for (n in 1:nrow(Final_Town_Contacts)){
if(str_detect(zadavatele$buyer_name[i], Final_Town_Contacts$Name[n] && 
              !is.na(str_detect(zadavatele$buyer_name[i], Final_Town_Contacts$Name[n]))))
  zadavatele$id[n] = Final_Town_Contacts$`LAU 2`
}
}
```

But that did not work. Do you have any idea how to make this work?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Does this work, So only the matching names will be included as because of inner join. The buyer_name's first character is matched with Name column. Please let me know if that won't be the case always.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(Name = substr(buyer_name,1,1)) %>% inner_join(df2) %>% select(1,3)
Joining, by = "Name"
  buyer_name id
1     xx abc 32
2      y fdg 54
3      z sad 11
```